# Is there a third pseudo element, like after and before

Tags: css

I need something like third pseudo element for `.foo.bar`.

```css
.foo.bar:before { content: "x "; }
.foo.bar:after { content: " x"; }

.foo.bar:before:before { content: "bad "; color: red; }
```

```html
<div class="foo">apple</div>
<div class="foo bar">orange</div>
<div class="foo">chainsaw</div>
```

Comment: i don't really understand what you want to achieve. you want to change the content of the `.foo.bar:before` or what ?

Comment: I simple want to make div with `foo` and `bar` classes filled with content `bad x orange x`, should be clear since i provide runable snippet

Comment: @Roko C. Buljan Yep, i get it now, sory for your confusion

Comment: @Sojtin no problem! :)

Comment: This was actually in the proposal of one of the early CSS3 draft specifications, chaining ::before and ::after psuedo-elements together. Unfortunately, it did not make it through to the final specification.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. It's **not** possible (using CSS) to prepend to `::before` or `::after`'s `content:`, or in other words — make a `content:"x";` become `bad x` cause any defined rule will overwrite the old one, and there's no *third* to `::before` and `::after` pseudo elements.